# Comparar ng if en angular

Tags: angularjs

Estoy intentando comparar

```
ng-repeat="conversation in vm.conversations" ng-if="conversation=second">
```

`conversation` con el valor `"second"`

Cual es mi error ?

Comment: la comparación es con `==` , además las comillas simples al valor ...  `ng-repeat="conversation in vm.conversations" ng-if="conversation=='second'">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes utilizar el operador de comparacion `==` y deberia ser asi :

```
ng-if="conversation=='second'"
```

Recuerda que el valor que buscas es `'second'`, es un texto y debe ir dentro de comillas

Answer (score 3):

Deberías comparar de esta manera:

```
conversation == second
```

Al usar un solo `=` estás realizando una asignación y no una comparación.

Espero que sea lo que estás buscando, sino puede volver a preguntar todas las veces que necesites.